# F# Convert 'a discriminated union to string

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, discriminated-union

I'm trying to convert a discriminated union to string but I don't understand why this code is not working.

```
type 'a sampleType =
 | A of 'a
 | B of 'a

let sampleTypeToString x =
 match x with
 | A (value) -> string value
 | B (value) -> string value
```

This is the fsharp interactive output

```
sampleTypeToString A(2);;
 Stopped due to error
 System.Exception: Operation could not be completed due to earlier error
 Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized at 3,19
 This expression was expected to have type
     'obj'    
 but here has type
     'int'     at 3,21
```

Comment: You'll need to `box` this: `sampleTypeToString (A(box(6)))`.

Comment: This is a shortcut that will make this specific example work, but you have to agree that this is not what was intended.

Comment: No, that's why it was just a comment :) But I was wondering if this can done without inline.

Comment: Yes, it can. There are two options in my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two errors here: function application syntax and lost genericity.

### Function application syntax

This is the error "*function arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled...*"

In the expression `sampleTypeToString A(2)`, you actually have *three* terms, not two:

1. `sampleTypeToString`
2. `A`
3. `(2)`

Don't let the lack of a space between `A` and `(2)` fool you. These are not considered, somehow, as "one expression". `A` and `(2)` are separate terms.

Therefore, the whole expression `sampleTypeToString A(2)` is being interpreted as function `sampleTypeToString` applied to two arguments - `A` and `(2)`. This, of course, doesn't work, because `sampleTypeToString` takes only one argument, and term `A` doesn't fit, because it's of the wrong type.

The simplest way to fix it is to just put parentheses around what should be evaluated first:

```
   sampleTypeToString (A(2))
```

And of course, since function (or constructor) application in F# doesn't actually require parentheses by itself, you can drop the first set:

```
   sampleTypeToString (A 2)
```

Alternatively, you can use a pipe:

```
   sampleTypeToString <| A(2)
```

This works, because the pipe operator has lower precedence than function application (which is the highest of all), so that `A(2)` gets evaluated first, and only then piped into `sampleTypeToString`.

### Lost genericity

This has to do with the error "*expected `obj`, but here has type `int`*"

This one is a bit trickier. See how you're using the `string` function within `sampleTypeToString`? That function is technically generic, but not in the regular way. It uses [statically resolved type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters). Without going into too much detail, this basically means that the concrete type of the argument has to be known at compile time.

But your function `sampleTypeToString` takes a parameter of generic type `sampleType<'a>`, and thus when it calls `string`, it passes the argument of type `'a`. But `string` can't work like that: it needs to know the concrete type, can't be generic `'a`. So the compiler tries its best to substitute a concrete type. Because it knows literally nothing of what `'a` could be, it goes with the most general assumption `obj`.

As a result, your function `sampleTypeToString` actually ends up taking parameter of type `sampleType<obj>`, not `sampleType<'a>` as you might expect.

The solution? Declare you function as `inline`. This will tell the compiler not to actually compile it as a .NET method, but rather expand its definition wherever it's called (somewhat similar to a `DEFINE` in C or a template in C++). This way, the type `'a` will always be known at compile time, and the picky function `string` would be satisfied.

```
let inline sampleTypeToString x =
 match x with
 | A (value) -> string value
 | B (value) -> string value

sampleTypeToString (A 2)
sampleTypeToString (B "abc")
sampleTypeToString (A true)
```

Alternatively, you could box the argument of `string`, turning it into `obj`:

```
let sampleTypeToString x =
 match x with
 | A (value) -> string (box value)
 | B (value) -> string (box value)
```

But then you'd slightly change the semantics of `string`, for it has [special processing for certain types](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L4473), converting to string in culture-invariant way. If you box the argument, it will basically always fall back to `obj.ToString()`. Plus, you'd suffer an extra heap allocation for the boxed value.

Even more alternatively, you could do away with `string` and just call `.ToString()` yourself:

```
let sampleTypeToString x =
 match x with
 | A (value) -> value.ToString()
 | B (value) -> value.ToString()
```

Keep in mind that this is not *exactly* the same as calling `string`.

Comment: This not completely fix the issue, combining with @s952163 solution work

Comment: Yes, I was updating it. Too much to write, couldn't post it all in one go. But notice that @s952163's solution doesn't actually give you what you want. Boxing the number turns it from `int` to `obj`, so that you lose the whole point of having `sampleType` generic.