# F# type obj but I want 'a

Tags: list, recursion, f#, functional-programming

I defined a type

```
type 'a sexp =
| E of 'a
| T of ( sexp<'a> * sexp<'a> );;
```

Example:

( "this" . (("is" . "a") . ( "s" .  "expression")) )

is a sexp of strings.

( ( 1 . 5 ) . 2 )

is a sexp of int.

---

And I made a function tolist that given an expression returns a list with the format.

```
let rec tolist expr =
match expr with
| Null -> [" "]
| E(x) -> [string x]
| T(l,r) -> 
    let l = tolist l
    let r = tolist r
    ["("]@(l)@[" . "]@(r)@[")"];;
```

val tolist : expr:obj sexp -> string list

My problem is that I want 'a sexp and not a obj sexp like is telling me. Where I did wrong?

A call is like that 
tolist (T(E("this") , E("is")));;

Answer (score 6):

The `string` function in F# has the type `obj -> string`, so it's constraining the type of `x` in your `E(x)` to be `obj`. (**Update:** It's slightly more complicated than that; see the second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232977/f-convert-a-discriminated-union-to-string/43233285#43233285) for all the details. But it boils down to "`string` needs to know the concrete type of its argument at compile time, so that it can call the right `.ToString()` method. And if you pass it a generic type, the only concrete type it can be *certain* will work is `obj`, so it ends up constraining your generic type to `obj`.") And that, in turn, is constraining the type of your `tolist` function to be `sexp<obj>` (or `obj sexp` -- same type, different way of writing it).

If you replace the `string` call with `sprintf "%A"` instead, your function will be properly generic. E.g., you want your code to look like this:

```
type 'a sexp =
| E of 'a
| T of ( sexp<'a> * sexp<'a> )

let rec tolist expr =
    match expr with
    | Null -> [" "]
    | E(x) -> [sprintf "%A" x]
    | T(l,r) -> 
        let l = tolist l
        let r = tolist r
        ["("]@(l)@[" . "]@(r)@[")"]
```

Comment: `string` does not take `obj`. It is generic, but with static constraints. See the second part of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43233285/180286

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - Thanks for the correction. I'll update my answer to link to that one, since you've already explained it better than I could.